# How Matlab knows the function that a vector is produced by to calculate cumtrapz?

Tags: matlab, function, integral

I have maybe a silly question. 
When I write the following script in Matlab y=[1 4] and then when I use cumtrapz(y) I get [0 2.5]. I know cumtrapz thinks the deltaX=1 in this method.
My question is that how matlab knows the vector 1,4 is created by f(x)=x^2?
one could say it is created by f(x)=3x-2 by just identifying y vector values or many other type of functions. So How matlab knows which function has produced Y vector in order to approximate the integration of the function?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB has no idea where those value came from

```
a = [1 4 5 9]
s = cumtrapz(a)
s =
0.00000    2.50000    7.00000   14.00000
```

standard step is **1** so:

```
h = 1;
s(i) = s(i-1) + h*(a(i-1)+a(i))/2
```

Answer (score 3):

Matlab does not know that your vector had been created by `f(x) = x^2`. `trapz` computes a **linear** interpolation between each pair of values.

So `cumtrapz` simply computes a 2 by 2 moving sum and then divides the result by 2.

```
% Sample data
Y = [1 4 9 16 25];

% Using cumtrapz
Q1  = diff(cumtrapz(Y))
%Q1 = [2.5, 6.5, 12.5, 20.5]

% Using a moving sum
Q2  = conv(Y,ones(2,1),'valid')/2
%Q2 = [2.5, 6.5, 12.5, 20.5]
```

Graphical example with `f(x) = sin(x)`:

[image]

`cumtrapz` simply applies `cumsum` the values of the intermediate points.

Comment: Thanks but still I am confused. If the function is assumed to be f(x)=x^2 the analytical solution of Ingeral of fx between 0 to 1 is x^3/3 between 1 to 2 which is 2.5 ( the same as the answer from matlab). But what you mentioned is that Matlab just used line between each two points. In this case the function becomes f(x)=3x-2 and the integral of this function analytically is (3x^2/2-2x) between 1 to 2 which is 1.5

Comment: If `f(x) = x^2` then, indeed, `F(x) = x^3/3`. To calculate the integral between `1` and `2` we use `F(2) - F(1) ` and the result is `2.3333` not `2.5`. So there is a difference between the numerical and the analytical solution since `trapz` use a linear approximation for a non-linear function.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway in Matlab for numerical integration to also enter the function parameters too and chose small dx for integration?

Comment: Check the `trapz` documentation. You can use `trapz(x,y)`, with `y = f(x)` and `x = start:dx:stop`. In this case `dx` can be as small as needed. But keep in mind that a numerical solution is always an approximation of the analytical solution, perhaps a really good approximation, but an approximation.